# javascript mutationObserver stop and start with button

Tags: javascript

hey i was just wondering would there be anyway to start and stop an mutationObserver with a button? and is my observer even right the this is first time i have used an observer.

```
respawn = function() {

  var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('hud-respawn-btn')[0];
  var life = document.getElementsByClassName('hud-health-bar-inner')[0];
  var dead = 1;

  spawns = function() {
    buttons.attributes.class.value = 'hud-respawn-btn';
    buttons.click();
  };

  var observer2 = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutationRecord) {
      if (parseInt(mutations[0].target.style.width) < dead) {
        console.log("it works")
        spawns();
      }
    });
  });

  observer2.observe(life, {
    attributes: true,
    attributeFilter: ['style']
  });
};
```

-

```
<button onclick=\"respawn();\">respawn</button>
```

Comment: if you remove the backslashes in the onclick it should work. You can check by using console.log('hello') when that function runs and checking in dev tools

Comment: Are you sure you even need a mutation Observer? Don't you have access to what does change your element's style.width? That would be a lot cleaner, and less intensive for the browser. But if you really want to do it, declare your MO and keep a flag (e.g a Boolean) to know if it's currently active outside of the click event. Then in the click event if(flag) [observer.disconnect();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/disconnect) else [observer.observe(target, options);](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe)